# GDB access hardware register

Tags: gdb, powerpc

I'm debugging a PowerPC design that utilizes the DCR bus.  Assembly instructions are required to access this bus.  I would like to access DCR registers via GDB interactive debugging.

Is there a way to create a GDB command (macro?) which would run assembly instructions to read/write the DCR bus?